# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#reading data
data = pd.read_csv('Malicious_or_criminal_attacks_breakdown-Top_five_industry_sectors_July-Dec-2019.csv',index_col=0,engine='python')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#df list for data
df.values.tolist()

#construction of group bar chart
labels = ('Cyber incident', 'Theft of paperwork or data storagedevice', 'Rogue employee', 'Social engineering / impersonation')
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']
data = df.values.tolist()
arr = np.array(data)


n_groups, n_colors = arr.shape
width = 0.2
x_pos = np.arange(n_colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
for i in range(n_groups):
    plt.bar(x_pos + i*width, arr[i, :], width, align='center', label=labels[i], color=colors[i])
ax.set_xlabel("the top five industry sectors")
ax.set_ylabel("Number of attack")
ax.set_title("Type of attack by top five industry sectors")

ax.set_xticks(x_pos+width/2)
ax.set_xticklabels(colors)

ax.legend()
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here and why numpy isnt working as expected.Ive looked at documantation for hours and cant figure out whats wrong

Comment: `ax` is an `ndarray` of subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ax` is an array of subplots because you created more than one. So in order to set the titles of the subplots, you need to iterate through them as well. You could fix this fairly easily like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
for i in range(n_groups):
    plt.bar(x_pos + i*width, arr[i, :], width, align='center', label=labels[i], color=colors[i])

for subplot in ax:
    subplot.set_xlabel("the top five industry sectors")
    subplot.set_ylabel("Number of attack")
    subplot.set_title("Type of attack by top five industry sectors")

    subplot.set_xticks(x_pos+width/2)
    subplot.set_xticklabels(colors)
    
    subplot.legend()
```

If you want to set different titles and stuff for different subplots, you need to adjust for that.

Comment: It throws an error "index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2"

Comment: Well that is because I assumed n_groups was 2. In that case, you need to separate the loops. I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: thank you this helps me understand it a lot better